# Как при соединении n таблиц потом прописать условия для удаления строк?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, drop

В цикле соединяется n-ое количество csv файлов. В связи с этим образуются столбцы с похожими названиями отличающиеся суффиксами
Пример полученной таблицы для n = 3:

| id | class | count | class_1 | count_1 | num_0_1 | class_2 | count_2 | num_0_2 | num_1_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | people | 2 | people | 3 | 0.6 | people | 2 | 0.75 | 0.8 |
| 2 | hare | 2 | hare | 2 | 0.77 | hare | 2 | 0.86 | 0.83 |
| 3 | people | 2 | empty | 2 | 0.86 | people | 2 | 0.85 | 0.79 |

Из этой таблице необходимо удалить строки удовлетворяющие следующим условиям:

1. Значения в столбцах class, class_1 ,class_2,...,class_(n-1) должны быть равны;
2. Значения в столбцах count, count_1, count_2,..., count_(n-1) должны быть равны;
3. Значения в столбцах num_0_1, num_0_2, num_1_2,..., num_(n-2)_(n-1) должны быть больше 0.7

Все эти условия должны выполняться одновременно для все столбцов

Так в примере должна получится следующая таблица:

| id | class | count | class_1 | count_1 | num_0_1 | class_2 | count_2 | num_0_2 | num_1_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | people | 2 | people | 3 | 0.6 | people | 2 | 0.75 | 0.8 |
| 3 | people | 2 | empty | 2 | 0.86 | people | 2 | 0.85 | 0.79 |

Я могу вытащить названия столбцов в листы, так для столбцов содержащих num я это делаю следующим образом

```
    list_col = []
    
    for i in range(df.shape[1]):
        if 'num_' in df.columns[i]:
            list_col.append(df.columns[i])
```

Но как дальше прописать условия для этих столбцов и удалить строки придумать пока не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для приведенного вами датафрейма можно сделать так:

```
n=3
res = df.loc[(df[df.filter(regex=fr"[class|count]_[^{n}]")
                 .nunique(axis=1)>2]
                 .filter(regex=fr"num_[^{n}]")>0.7).index]
```

res:

```
     class  count class_1  count_1  num_0_1 class_2  count_2  num_0_2  num_1_2
id                                                                            
1   people      2  people        3     0.60  people        2     0.75     0.80
3   people      2   empty        2     0.86  people        2     0.85     0.79
```

**UPDATE**

В виду не полной ясности условия и нерепрезентативности исходных данных автора вопроса, могу предположить, что в конечном итоге нужно будет решать задачу так:

```
res = df.loc[df.filter(regex=r"[class|count]_").nunique(axis=1)>2]
res = res[res.filter(like=r"num_").apply(lambda x: x.le(0.7).all() , axis=1)]
```

Comment: А как таким образом мне прописать третье условие из вопроса сразу для всего числа колонок?

Comment: я исправил ответ конкретно под ваш вопрос.

Comment: спасибо,  у меня получилось вписать первые два условия таким образом 
`df[df.filter(regex=fr"class" and fr"count").nunique(axis=1)!=1]` , а как можно вписать третье?

Comment: Еще раз исправил ответ. Меня смущает обилие у вас подобных условий. Обычно это говорит о неэффективной подготовке данных.

Comment: А вот сейчас выполняется последовательно, вначале смотрит равные значения, а потом ещё проверяет третье условие. И удаляются строки, которые удовлетворяют только первому и второму условию. Можно это как-то поправить?

Comment: У вас нерепрезентативные данные, поэтому по ним я не могу проверить решение. тем не менее, я обновил ответ. надеюсь, я правильно понял, что вам нужно.